# Disabling Thumbnails tab of Document Browser in Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is there any way to disable the Thumbnails tab of `Autodesk.DocumentBrowser` extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `panel.setThumbnailVisibility` or setup `showThumbnails: false` in the option instead, _ prefix variable should be treated as internal/private variable to JavaScript object due to lack of private property support in ECMAScript 5.

```
viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.DocumentBrowser', {showThumbnails: false});

//OR
const documentBrowserExt = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.DocumentBrowser')
documentBrowserExt.ui.panel.setThumbnailVisibility(false)
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution.

```
NOP_VIEWER.getExtension('Autodesk.DocumentBrowser').ui.panel._showThumbnails = false;
```